# Will sealing ceiling with foil paper introduce any problems?

Tags: ceiling, paint

At some point I’m going to paint or shellac then paint this ceiling.  I’ve covered the cause of the peeling in another question so please don’t worry about that - it’s because of humidity due to not using the extractor fan.

Until I do the repair, would there be any problem if removed all the current paint then covered the ceiling with foil paper and taped it up with painters masking tape to temporarily hold the plaster smell in?

Or might this damage the ceiling in any way so it’s best not to?  I don’t really shower there at the moment so condensation isn’t a problem plus extractor fan is on.

[image]

Comment: Why  wait ? It will take nearly as long to cover it in foil paper as it will to paint it.

Comment: I would suggest painting right away, if not a very inexpensive painters drop cloth made out of plastic would be better 1 piece would seal and the leftovers can cover the tub when you do go to paint. I believe a 10’ square made to cover furniture and trash when done was 2$ I think they had 24’ square for 5$ it is thin but I use as a dust barrier when taking out old fireplaces and cutting trenches in concrete if it can contain concrete dust and paint spills it should work for a oder blocker.